# How can I get the CORS working for the POST to the Lambda function URL?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I am getting CORS error when making ajax request to the AWS lambda function url from browser.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://somethingsomething.lambda-url.us-east-2.on.aws/authnz/subscribe. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

My Lambda Function URL' CORS is configured as below . However, browser is still throwing error when my JQUERY makes POST call.
[image]

JQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: remoteUrl,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+token
      },
      data:  {"a":"aa"},
      success: function(response) {
         
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        
        $("#form_save_message").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

The response headers for the `OPTIONS` calls are
[image]

How can I get the CORS working for the POST to the Lambda function URL? I am not using API gateway just the Lambda function URL. Do I must use API Gateway ?  From what I have seen every question here is with API gateway + Lambda.

My Backend code, just have some business logic and looks like this :

```
public class RegistrationApplication implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>> {
     

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> handleRequest(Map<String, Object> requestParams, Context context) {
        Map<String,Object> lambdaResponse = new HashMap<>();
        return lambdaResponse;
    }
}
```

Note,

1. my lambda is written in Java
2. I am not seeing the lambda handler logs rolling when OPTIONS calls is made by browser  so adding headers in the function
   `public Map<String, Object> handleRequest(Map<String, Object> requestParams, Context context) {` will have no effect.

Comment: Hi, could you share us your Function definition code? What methods are you using? What integration type are you using between the API gateway to lambda? HTTP Proxy or HTTP?

Comment: A necessary condition for CORS preflight to succeed for your client is that `Content-Type` be listed as an allowed request header in your CORS configuration. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Comment: @AllanChua I have updated my  question with the code, I am not using API Gateway . It is just Lambda triggered by it's function URL.

Comment: @jub0bs In the shared screenshot of response headers from `OPTIONS` you can see `content-type` set. However, I have explicitly added the 'content-type' in the "Expose headers" configuration of Lambda as you suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: @Geek You need to list `Content-Type` under the rubric entitled _Allow headers_, not the one entitled _Expose headers_.

Comment: @jub0bs You are right , I didn't notice that my jQuery is sending `content-type` header to the backend. Adding `content-type` in the "Allow headers" fixed the  problem .

Answer (score 0):

For me, CORB issue happened when I had configured the API Gateway with proper CORS configurations, but my Lambda function written in .NET was not returning proper CORS header in the response. This was resulting in successful OPTIONS request but was failing while making GET or POST requests to the API Gateway.

A simple solution for you would be to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your Java Lambda function.

I am not a JAVA guy, so please excuse me if I am wrong below. But this is just to show you how can you return the required header from the Lambda function.

```java
public Response handleRequest(RequestClass request, Context context){
    .
    .
    .
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, "*"); // Required CORS header

    return new Response(200, headers, responseBody);
}
```

Comment: My `OPTIONS` call is failing it never reaches to me. I think Server corresponding to Lambdas  handle the `OPTIONS` call and returns the response without the headers.  Note , I am not using API Gateway is it a must requirement to use?

Comment: Did you try my solution? I think it should work even though when you are not using API Gateway. Similar to API Gateway, you have configured CORS settings directly in Lambda. Please give this solution a try and see if the issue is still persisting.

Comment: And I can clearly see, your OPTIONS requests are successful as the screenshot you posted is showing 200 status code.

Comment: I did try , but it didn't work.  Also , OPTIONS request is succeeding but the response headers doesn't contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that's why browser deem it failure.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some online reading, debugging and taking help from other comments I figured out that my jQuery was sending `content-type` and `authorization` headers.

So there are two ways to fix this:

1. In the original question, I already allowed the "authorization" headers but the ajax was also sending `content-type` headers because of this line `contentType: "application/json"` in the ajax call. So I updated the ajax call to `dataType: "json",`.
2. Or, you add both the headers (`contentType` and `authorization` ) in the "Allow headers" of the Function URL.

This article explains how to debug CORS: https://medium.com/@mail.ekansh/cors-with-lambdas-function-url-22bb5bfcb3c4